# Gradle flatDir with version in the middle of file name

Tags: gradle, wildcard, android-gradle-plugin, dependency-management

I have the following file in a flat directory: `foo-x-1.0.3-banana.jar`. Notice the file version is not at the end but in the middle of the file name.

Currently this file is imported using `compile 'com.example.foo:foo-x-1.0.3-banana:1.0.3@jar'`.

I'd like to make gradle understand this file naming convention such that an import can be made using `compile ':foo-x-*-banana:1.0.3@jar'` or similar. Notice that I've replaced the version in the file name with a `*` because I don't know what to put there.

Is there a wildcard I can use to match anything in there? I know that for the version there are wildcards (I only know `+` though).

---

Edit/clarification:
To import the file `foo-2.5.jar` I can use `compile ':foo:2.+@jar'`. Gradle can pick up the version at the end of the file name. How can I import a file if the version is not at the end of the file name but in the middle, for example `foo-2.5-foo.jar`?

Comment: What's the `*` supposed to be in your proposed example? The version? Any what's the problem you are try to solve?

Comment: @BenjaminMuschko: Yes, `*` was supposed to be a wildcard for the version. I've added some more information. Basically I had a file that didn't follow the convention of having the version at the end and I didn't know how to import it in a way that it would support future versions of the jar without change. Using `':foo-x-1.0.3-banana:1.0.3@jar'` works for the current version but once I update the jar to version 1.0.4 the import will break. Using `':foo-x-1.0.+-banana:1.0.+@jar'` won't work because the version is in the middle.